# Error when adding a user

Tags: database, magento2.2, mariadb, user-account

When I try to create a user, I get this error:

*"Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly."*

In system log I get:
 main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is the full error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.

Exception #0 (Exception): Rolled back transaction has not been completed correctly.
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->commit() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:420]
#2 Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(&Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor#000000007a794cb800000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:647]
#3 Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#4 Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->___callParent('save', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#5 Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#6 Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->___callPlugins('save', array(), array(array('revokeTokensFrom...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/User/Model/User/Interceptor.php:26]
#7 Magento\User\Model\User\Interceptor->save() called at [vendor/magento/module-user/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Save.php:89]
#8 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:107]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:235]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#11 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#12 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#13 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save\Interceptor#000000007a7948bb00000000472f7b0c#, &Closure#000000007a7948b500000000472f7b0c#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#14 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/User/Controller/Adminhtml/User/Save/Interceptor.php:26]
#16 Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:55]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000007a794aba00000000472f7b0c#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:257]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000007a794a4600000000472f7b0c#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```